Flutter Web GoRouter - chrome refresh issue
I have a flutter app for mobile and I am porting it to web. I have implemented the Go Router package. I have singleton classes in my code which save the login_info so that I can access them later on dashboard etc. The chrome refresh works fine on login screen but after login on dashboard I get the red screen with unexpected null value text.
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building Builder:
Unexpected null value.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Navigator-[LabeledGlobalKey<NavigatorState>#6e84c]
  Navigator:file:///Users/ichi14/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/go_router-14.2.1/lib/src/builder.dart:429:16

Do i need to use some local cache for this login info? on refresh singletons get destroyed?
How can I keep these profile information accessible through the app?
login_info is a model class kept in the singleton

Yes, you need to cache any data that needs to be available after refreshing the page, since When you refresh the page, the entire app is destroyed and launched again. This is how the browser works, nothing specific to Flutter here. So the values of local variables are expected to disappear.
